# DataTable search filter is always returning "No matching records found"

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to filter result records by a keyword. But when I enter a keyword, data-table always display **"No matching records found"** message.

It should display related record matching keyword typed by user.

**LIVE Demo:** http://live.datatables.net/havusebu/2/watch

Not sure my HTML markup is missed up or what can be the issue that search filter isn't working?

**UPDATE:** In my HTML I have used `data-*` attributes for filtering records which is causing the issue. But why will data-search attribute cause this issue? By removing the below data-search attributes search filter is working. But when `data-search=` is present in the HTML it's not working. How can I make it working with `data-search` attribute?

```
<td data-search="blog">
```

Comment: Where is your html demo?

Comment: @vadivel a http://live.datatables.net/payuteka/1/watch?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: I can see from your demo, that DataTable's default filtering is not working because your table is not a `<table></table>` but a list of `<div>` which is not the html structure it expects. regarding your `filterByType` function, you declare it but are never invoking it. please try to review your code and include it as a snippet in your question using the button `<>`, that way it will be easier for people on SO to help you

Comment: @scaramouche it is a table not a list of divs. Can you review the code again please? Filterbytype is called at the end of the body in script tag

Comment: it is a table, but I see every `<td>` contains a nested structure of `<div>`s which might be casuing the problem, also I still don't see `filterByType` being invoked anywhere, it is DECLARED at the end of the script but never INVOKED/EXECUTED, also there is like a thousand lines between `<tbdoy>` and the first `<tr>` in the demo

Comment: @Scaramouche filterByType is executed on selection/un-selection of checkbox, and that's not the issue. Along with that why would a div inside td disturbs the search filter? Another thing is that `Show 10 entires` feature is working if you change the number to 50 or any other but search filter isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging finally found the solution (:

I just added an extra hidden **td** `<td style="display:none;" data-search="{{ hit['_source']['filter'] }}"></td>` and removed `data-search` from the below **td**

```
<td data-search="{{ hit['_source']['filter'] }}">
```

and now both filter and search is working.

**LIVE DEMO**: http://live.datatables.net/jitaguce/1/watch